# Problem with additionally starting konsoles when booting (debian)

Tags: bash, boot, startup, konsole

I am using the following command to start a konsole + execute a command at startup.

```
konsole -e 'bash -c "MY_COMMAND;bash"'
```

The goal is that the konsole stays open after executing the command (which does work as it is intended).

But after shutting down (or rebooting) my system, not only this 1 konsole with the command executed inside does open, but one additional (without any command executed inside).

With 2 of such startup scripts, if i don't close all konsoles mannually before shutting down, 4 terminals will open (2 as intended + 2 'clean').

Does anyone have an explanation why this happens? Why does each command open another bash if i don't close them manually before rebooting ?

I thought shutting down via KDE or using the shutdown command should close all terminals, so why is this even happening at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to this site!

It's been ages since I last used KDE, but if I remember correctly, it *saves* the current session on logout/shutdown and automatically restore *every* open application on login **by default**.

There's should be an option to disable this function under

> Settings → Autostart → Session Management

[image: KDE Setting for session management]